# VBA code working in one Workbook but not another

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a code in a Workbook but I am doing a new project, I want to reuse the code, I copy and paste it. But I have this error message :

**Method or Data Member not Find**

The code is as follow, and it is highlighting this :

rates.Add Conversion.**Val**(node.getAttribute("rate")), node.getAttribute("currency")

I do not understand why val is highlighted in my new workbook but no in my previous one.

I am seeking your help :)

```
Public Function ConvCurrency(Value As Double, fromSymbol As String, toSymbol As String)
 
  Static rates As Collection, expiration As Date  ' cached / keeps the value between calls '

    If fromSymbol = "SAR" Then
        ConvCurrency = Value * 0.2
    
    Else:

        If DateTime.Now > expiration Then
            Dim xhr As Object, node As Object
            expiration = DateTime.Now + DateTime.TimeSerial(1, 0, 0) ' + 1 hour '

            Set rates = New Collection
            rates.Add 1#, "EUR"
   
            Set xhr = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
    
            xhr.Open "GET", "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml", False
            xhr.send
 
            For Each node In xhr.responseXML.SelectNodes("//*[@rate]")
                rates.Add Conversion.Val(node.getAttribute("rate")), node.getAttribute("currency")
            Next
        End If

        ConvCurrency = (Value / rates(fromSymbol)) * rates(toSymbol)
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: What happens if you use `VBA.Conversion.Val`?

Comment: Thank you BigBen, it is working. Could you explain me what I was missing. 
It worked before, and now I need to use VBA. 
Why is that?

Comment: Something else (another library, one of your modules perhaps) is shadowing the `Conversion`... normally one just uses `Val`, or you can use the entire `VBA.Conversion.Val`.